# Import statements taking time on spark executors (Pyspark Executors)

Tags: apache-spark, tensorflow, keras, pyspark, spark-streaming

I am developing a python prediction script using Spark (PySpark) streaming and Keras. The prediction is happening on the executor where I am calling model.predict().

Modules that I have imported are

```
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation, Dropout 
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM 
from keras.models import Sequential
```

I have checked and these imports are taking 2.5 seconds on Spark driver(2 cor + 2gb) to load. What is surprising for me is that each time executor gets the job, it automatically do these imports again. The reason I am sure that these imports are happening each time a job is submitted to the executor is because I see below statements in executor logs per job which are only comes when I do imports of above said modules.

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype fromfloattonp.floatingis deprecated. In future, it will be treated asnp.float64 == np.dtype(float).type. from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters Using TensorFlow backend.
```

My target is to make the prediction in 1 sec but imports itself are taking 2.5 seconds (each time imports happens on the spark executor). Is this is the intended behavior? Is their anything I can do to minimize this time say in milliseconds ?

**Update 1**

For the past few days I was analyzing it and found out that there are 2 main issues.

1. I found a way to wrap keras model and pickle it on driver and unpickle on executor. So that improves time by 1 sec.
2. But on driver when mapPartition() occur for each batch the whole keras and tensorflow initialization happens each time on executor (for every job) which is taking 2.5 secs. Is there a way to initialize these imports once on each executor and not per job. May be some file in pyspark where can I put these imports(assuming that these files executed once when executor comes up)

Comment: I don't know much about spark streaming, but are you using a map function?

Comment: @tim I am using mapPartitions

Comment: That was going to be my suggestion, import once with mapPartitions instead of per row with map. Can't help more than that, I'm unfamiliar with the streaming side of spark.

Comment: @Tim Thanks for the suggestion. Please see the updated answer. May be something you can help me on.

Comment: 2 thoughts: 1. I don't think you need to pickle the model on driver and unpickle on executors. using `spark.sparkContext.addPyFile(keras files)` should allow you to directly download it to the executors. 2. Using mapPartitions implies the model will be downloaded/instantiated exactly 1X/partition (not job or executor). This may not help directly but you could try to `coalesce` to fewer partitions if model instantiation is slower than prediction.

Comment: @Tim I understand but my primary and only issue is I need a way to load these imports only once when executor initialize. Either that or I want that all my jobs use same Python processes to execute and it should not create new processes for each and every job. I tried using spark.python.worker.reuse='true' but got no improvement.

Comment: `coalesce` your data to 1 partition per executor. 1 executor, 1 model load.

Comment: @Tim If I coalesce it to 1 partition then I don't think I can scale it further because since there will be a single partition, it always execute by 1 executor. Isn't it ? More over, when the data for 2nd batch comes then all imports will be loaded again on executor which is the real bottleneck. I assume there is no such support for my use case in spark and I just have to live with it.

Comment: if you have like 50 executors (pretty normal for spark) you can coalesce to 50 partitions. you get the benefits of parallelization with a single model load per executor. "More over, when the data for 2nd batch comes then all imports will be loaded again on executor which is the real bottleneck." <- Not sure about this, I'm not to familiar with the streaming side.

Comment: @Tim I understand the concept of coalesce, but my issue is related to imports happening again and again per job as importing keras which is internally importing tensorflow is taking too much time per job(Nearly 2.5 sec to import) and I do understand that you don't have solution to my problem and nobody else is commenting anything so I guess it is a lost cause.