# Add python import statements to Pyspark code

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to add few python imports to the existing pyspark code. My intention is that as there must be some file which is being used to load the executor and later execute jobs on it.

My problem is that If I put these imports in a function which is being passed to  `mapPartition()` then these imports gets executed for each and every partition for each and every job which you see hindering the performance because imports are bit heavy(take 2.5 sec) which means that for each job on a partition before running function code it waste precious 2.5 sec in imports.

My idea/hinch is that there must be some function in a file (worker.py or daemon.py) in pyspark where I can put these imports so that they can be executed just once. I already went through code but not able to find solution to my problem. Am I on right track or Am I missing something ?

Comment: Why do imports take so long in the first place? Anyways, I believe you could add your imports here: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/worker.py#L367

Comment: @BlackBear I am not sure why they are taking so long. Even If I import them on my local machine having 4 cores and 8gb RAM, it takes about 2.5 sec. I assume tensorflow has heavy imports and native c++ code that takes time to load in memory. Also, I have tried added the code below L367 but didn't get any performance improvement and it's still importing them for each job. The reason I am sure is because I can see "Using TensorFlow backend." statement per partition execution which only comes when we import keras and tensorflow libraries. Any thoughts ? Am I doing it right as per your suggestion ?

Comment: I have edited worker.py like this. `def process():
            iterator = deserializer.load_stream(infile)
            serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
            from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation, Dropout
            from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
            from keras.models import Sequential`

Comment: You have to put the imports before `serializer.dump_stream` (that's where your function `func` gets called), and be sure to remove them from your own code

Comment: @BlackBear I have added the import before `serializer.dump_stream` but still getting same issue. imports been executed again and again on executors. I can not remove the imports from program because then my driver complaints that imports are not defined. I have asked related question few days back. Perhaps this can give you more insights. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52715477/import-statements-taking-time-on-spark-executors-pyspark-executors

Comment: " I can not remove the imports from program because" I guess that is the problem :) you can catch the `NameError` in your program tho, and import what you need, something like `try: Dense; except NameError: from keras.layers.core import Dense` etc.